# How to methodologically show that a given 'time-series/sequential' data is not really sequential?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, sequential-analysis

I have an apparent time-series/sequencial (supervised: multi-class classification problem) dataset with each data-point time-stamped. However, some domain intuition tells me that the data is static and no need to treat them as time-series data. I have also verified that a non-timeseries method fits (even with rigorous cross-validation and other good practices) the data well. However, I want to prove this in more rigorous/methodological way, preferably in python but R is also fine if no alternative. Is there any method/test that validate my hypothesis?

Comment: Start with some plotting

Comment: Basically you want to show that your data is just white noise. No autocorrelation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Watson_statistic